# Transforming two different Geodetic CRS in pyproj using python?

Tags: pyproj

I failed to transform two different Geodetic CRS

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform

#Transform from Arc1950 to WGS84
inProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4209')
x1,y1 = 27.04892, -13.30552
x2,y2 = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print x2,y2
```

but the return:

```
27.04892 -13.30552
```

this is not a correct result, it should be  *27.04906, -13.30400*.(I got this correct result from Mapsource.)

Comment: If you have access to QGIS, you can do transformation using PyQGIS which gives you the correct results.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try PyQGIS. is there any module i can do as this?

Comment: I've added a post to describe how you could use it =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use QGIS, you can use the following code in the **Python Console** which uses the [QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html) class to transform your points:

```
old_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)
new_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4209)
transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(old_crs, new_crs)
transform_points = transform.transform(QgsPoint(27.04892, -13.30552))
print transform_points
```

This will print out:

```
(27.0491,-13.304)
```

[image]

---

If you want to use this outside QGIS such as in the **OSGeo4W shell** then you could use the [osgeo.osr.SpatialReference()](http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.osr.SpatialReference-class.html) class:

```
from osgeo import osr 
old_crs = osr.SpatialReference() 
old_crs.ImportFromEPSG(4326) 
new_crs = osr.SpatialReference() 
new_crs.ImportFromEPSG(4209) 
transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(old_crs,new_crs) 
transform_points = transform.TransformPoint(27.04892, -13.30552)
print transform_points[0], transform_points[1]
```

This should print out:

```
27.0490596011 -13.3039944497
```

[image: Standalone image]

Comment: thanks for your code, but i still failed to get the correct result, i couldn't post the capture here, i upload the capture to my google photo, https://goo.gl/photos/xmNGKJ9jWWrPyNwk7

Comment: @udbird - Good point, edited post to show another method :)

Comment: it is weird, i run these codes using ipython shell in ubuntu 12.04,  and failed again. Maybe there are some bugs with my linux, i will try the codes after i install osgeo module windows version. thanks for your helps. https://goo.gl/photos/xmNGKJ9jWWrPyNwk7

Comment: @udbird - Yes that is weird, hope you get the results when you install the windows version!

Comment: It works with windows version in my computer. thank u!

Comment: The osgeo module works with 2.7.6 version in ubuntu 14.04, but qgis failed.

Comment: @udbird - Glad it works (on Windows atleast)! Can't confirm the same issue for Ubuntu as I do not use it :)